# Float <div> element on top of table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When the `<div>` is expanded, the `table` gets expanded too. I intend to expand only the `<div>`, floating it over the table. How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").click(function() {
    $("div").css({
      "height": "100px"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>click</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could use `position: absolute;`, but be aware this will remove the `div` from the size calculation of the containing `td`, so it will have no height unless it contains other data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to set `position:absolute` for your div.

See [CSS Layout - The position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){
    $("div").css({"height":"100px"});
   });
 });
```

```css
div{
     background-color:grey;
   }
table tr td{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}
div{
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr><td>
    <div>click</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    2
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>click</td>
  <td>
    2
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>click</td>
  <td>
    2
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>
    click
  </td>
  <td>
    2
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```